# Grouping Fields

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i want to get the desired query in Sql using following tables

usertable
id name
1  Vikram
2  vik
3  ram

ProductTable
id   userid   productdetails      Active
1      1               XXXX                              Yes
2     1                YYYY                              NO
3     3                AAAA                              Yes
4      3               BBBB                             Yes
5      1               CCCC                            Yes

Now i want the result something like
Products which are active grouped by user paged by user

page 1
user 1
        Product 1
        product 2
        product 5
user 3
        Product 3

i am getting like
user 1       Product 1
User 1       Product 2
user 1       Product 5
user 3       Product 3

but i want something like this in single Query
user 1   Product1  Product2  Product 5
user 3   product3

Any Help will be appreciated
thanks & Regards
Vikram

Comment: Can you post your current query?

Comment: this is not an exact query, my actual table is very big and also contains lots of joining

Comment: Do you want the products for each user as comma separated values or as separate columns?

Comment: Separated Columns, but there is no limit on the product number

Comment: You can check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
      ev.userid
    , Product = STUFF(CAST((
        SELECT [text()] = ', ' + ev2.productdetails
        FROM #ProductTable ev2
        WHERE ev2.userid = ev.userid
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS VARCHAR(100)), 1, 2, '')            
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT userid
    FROM #ProductTable
) ev
```

output:

```
    userid  Product
    1       XXXX, YYYY, CCCC
    3       AAAA, BBBB
```

[String Aggregation in the World of SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691102/String-Aggregation-in-the-World-of-SQL-Server)

[Simulating group_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT User, ConcatProduct = 
(
    SELECT [text()] = A.Product + ' '
    FROM TableName A
    WHERE A.User = B.User 
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
FROM TableName B
GROUP BY User
```

After u get data like following run upper query.

```
user1      Product 1
user1      Product 2
user1      Product 5
user3      Product 3
```

Query is written assuming your first column name User and second column name Product. Output will be as following:

```
user1       Product 1  Product 2  Product 5
user3       Product 3
```